# Get Day "Thursday" from 2015-08-01 which is comming from calendar

Tags: javascript

friends i have an input field in which i show datepicker calendar which is showing and working perfectly. text field field date like this 2015-08-01. i want this date formate and also i want to get day from this date like "Thursday" i hope you getting my point.
when i click on any date in calender it shows date like this 2015-08-01 in input field and i get this field using on change and saving in a variable then i try to get day from it but failed. here are the code which i try

```
 var d = new Date();
 var n = String(d.getDay());
 alert(n);
```

also this one too

```
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
alert( days[d.getDay()] ) ;
```

Comment: The second way seems to work fine.

Comment: yes it work fine but it shows just current day i need every day like when i click on monday date calendar it has to show monday but it is just showing Thursday mean current day.

Comment: You'll need to post a complete code example then, including this calendar you have.

Comment: <input name="date" onchange="testing(this.value);" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="date" value"2015-08-01" />
value is dummy in this field now when i click on it and change value function is called and send this value to function now i have to change this value into "Thursday". if date is 2015-21-01 then it has to change into "Wednesday".

Comment: need to create date from your string . Without an argument `new Date()` is always `now`

Comment: @j08691 I think the example/question is pretty clear as-is: how to turn the date-string `"2015-08-01"` into `"Saturday"`? The code that generates the string isn't important. Currently the OP is getting a `Date` object for the *current* date, and wants to get one for an *arbitrary* date, described by a string. (Whether or not it shows sufficient research, etc., is a different matter, I guess, but the problem statement itself seems clear, and there's certainly enough information to formulate a solution.)

Comment: @apsillers if it requires as you are saying then the date format should be "var d = new Date("2015-01-08");"
not var d = new Date("2015-08-01");

Comment: will you please provide code i am not getting your point i am searching the solution about an hour.

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas hey second method is fine if you do it like

var d = new Date("2015-01-08");
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
alert( days[d.getDay()] ) ;

Take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/Bzdnm/1064/

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas or add the complete code in above jsfiddle

Comment: @sagar43 The problem with this is that the Date-instant will be midnight in UTC time, but the day-of-week reported in local time, so if you're in a negative time zone, it will be reported one day earlier. Your fiddle alerts "Wednesday" for me, which isn't correct (today is a Thursday).

Comment: @sagar43 yes i know 2nd one is working perfect but there is a problem with it. whatever date you enter it will show you current day. but i want day according to date. will you please do me a favor change that 2015-01-08 to 2015-01-10 and check also send me the link of jsfiddle. THanks

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas give me a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code hope this works
HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( {
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
         var d = new Date(date+" UTC");
alert(days[d.getDay()]);
     }
    });
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
```

js Fiddle [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzdnm/1065/)